# Adverse immigration history in the UK

Tags: passports, standard-visitor-visas

I had lived in the UK for the last five years on work visas. But I was unsuccessful on my renewal of my last visa application. I did not have an extension to stay in the country as my visa expired during the application and the Home Office held my visa. I left the UK within the 30-day voluntary leave period and my passport was returned back to me at the airport when I checked in for the flight I was flying out of. I plan to go back to the UK to visit friends within the next 3 months. Will I have issues when I get to the UK border? I only plan on visiting the UK for 2-3 weeks and I have a return flight booked.

Would getting a new passport with a new number be better for me?

Comment: Did you try to change from a work visa to another visa type?

Comment: The obvious question is under what grounds was your work visa renewal refused? was it refused for some mundane reason or was it refused because you had done something bad?

Comment: There is no grace period; the notice says that if an individual does not vacate within or by the end of 30 days, there may be sanctions. You now have an overstay on record, and it will be considered during any visa application. If a visa is granted, that will be a good thing. While the overstay will remain on record, a subsequent visa indicates acceptable explanation.

Comment: @Giorgio could you clarify about the overstay? I may need to edit or remove my answer below as I thought the asker had complied with the rules.

Comment: @user16259; yes; after my comment, GayfotFow PM'd me and [addressed it in his blog](https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/2018/03/25/overstaying-and-the-30-day-grace-period-clarification/). He's on sabbatical from TSE, but welcomes users here to extract/quote his content. Why don't you do that as part of your answer? If you need guidance on how to do it, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Changing your passport does not change who you are and will not make any difference to your chances of entering the UK.

Edit: The section below is not correct. As noted in comments, you do have an overstay record which will be considered in any future application.

[It sounds from your description like you don't really have an adverse history; when your application was rejected, you complied with the rules and left the UK.]

You can apply for a visit visa and as long as the visa office is satisfied that you meet the criteria, you will get a visit visa. You will need to show ties to your home country, such as having a job, and that you have enough money to pay for your trip.

Comment: I agree with the answer however that said I am doubtful he will receive a visa because it is strange that you never said your goodbyes and made your visits to friends, and suddenly after being refused an extension you want to go back so soon to do so. Does not make sense with me Leaving after your extension was denied is a positive thing, however I think he's trying to visit a bit too soon.

Comment: Also, the visa was refused; UK does not use 'reject' in its terminology.